# How can I reduce the size of my listview?

Tags: android

I got a listview containing images. the images load automatically as the user scrolls down. but after a while the list gets too big. how can I prune it?

I tried `removeViews(int start, int end)` but it doesnt seem to make a difference.

Whats the best to prune it so it doesnt get too large?

Comment: What do you mean by "the list gets too big"? `ListView` recycles rows, assuming that your adapter is not screwing this up.

Comment: @CommonsWare I mean the scroll bar cursor gets very small

Answer (score 1):

> how can I prune it?

The number of available rows in the `ListView` is determined by `getCount()` on your adapter. You are the one who set up your adapter, and therefore you are responsible, directly or indirectly, for what `getCount()` returned.

> I mean the scroll bar cursor gets very small

If you do not want that many rows in the `ListView`, do not create an adapter with so many rows.

You are also welcome to change the data inside the adapter, then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on `ListView`. If, in doing so, your `getCount()` returns a smaller number than before, the "scroll bar cursor" may be larger.